# Как сделать текст поверх изображения?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужно сделать так, чтобы определенный текст разного размера (заголовки статей допустим) можно было разместить поверх картинки.

На пример, как на сайте [onedio.ru](http://onedio.ru), где на главной странице заголовки статей находятся на картинке поста.

Как такое можно сделать?
Дайте материал по теме, а лучше фрагмент кода для реализации задуманного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block > span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.allwallpaper.in/wallpapers/1600x1200/4815/dandelions-flowers-macro-nature-white-1600x1200-wallpaper.jpg)">
  <span>Very very very long description text exiting of block visible area</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

position relative для контейнера, position absolute - для элементов, которые нужно наложить на другие объекты в этом контейнере